# Residue class as a subset of another residue class

Tags: number-theory

Im currently working on a problem on residue classes, but I dunno if words are enough to prove this or there is a mathematical way?

Prove that $M_{10} + \{2\} \subset M_5 + \{2\}$

I transformed $M_{10} + \{2\}$ as $a = 10m + 2$ => $a = 2(5m)+2$ and $M_5 + \{2\}$ as 
$b = 5m + 2$ but I have no idea how to proceed... any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we can ... just do it.

$M_{10} + 2 = \{10k + 2|k\in \mathbb Z\}$

$M_5 + 2 = \{5k + 2|k\in \mathbb Z\}$.

Easy to prove $\{10k + 2|k \in \mathbb Z\} = \{5*(2k)+2|k\in \mathbb Z\} = \{5a+2|a\in \text{ is any even integer}\} \subset \{5k+2|k \in \mathbb Z\}$.

=====

...or...

If you are like me, you may have had an initial instinct when first taught not to view a "modulo class" as a multivalued set but as so quasi number we can do a modified arithmetic on.

If we view it this way.

$M_{10} +\{2\}$ is some weird notation..... to express the idea of numbers of the form...  $a\equiv 2\mod 10$

We can easily prove $a\equiv 2\mod 10\implies a\equiv 2 \mod 5$ as $a\equiv 2\mod 10\implies a = 2 + 10k$ for some integer $k$ $\implies a= 2+ 5(2k) \implies a \equiv 2 \mod 5$.

..... then some how we have to figure out what that has to doe with saying that a  a modulo class is a "subset" of another... how weird....

Well.. translated.  $M_{10} + \{2\}$ is the modulo class (set) of all numbers that are congruent to $2 \mod 10$.  If $a$ is in that set, is simply to say  that $a$ is a number that is congruent  to $2 \mod 10$.  And if $a \equiv 2\mod 10$ then $a \equiv 2 \mod 5$ is easy to prove as we did above.  So if we refer $M_{5} +\{2\}$ as a class or set then $a \equiv 2 \mod 5$ means $a$ is such an number.

**In *set* concept, we just showed an element of one set is an element of another.**

So $M_{10}+\{2\}\subset M+_{5} + \{2\}$.

Moral:  Don't be afraid to think of modulo classes as sets.  And when you do the arithmetic on them, you can think of them as numbers... *if*, when asked, you are aware the the actual numbers you are mucking with are *representative* of a *class* of numbers.

Comment: hahaha! My idea is so near, but I didnt realize that tnx a lot :)

Comment: modulo classes are sets/classes.  Might as well treat them like it.

Comment: You see mathematics beyond the way I see it... Your philosphy in this field is way far than mine.. Hope I learn from U a lot :)  Thanks for enlightenment :)